# Do i need a print server at each remote site?

Tags: active-directory, network-printer, print-server

I am planning a network for a project and am wondering how to proceed with print services.  This topology has a main office with 2 remote branch offices.  I plan to create one domain with 2 remote sites.  If I wanted to deploy a print server to this domain do I need one at each remote site?  I can imagine that in the event that the site to site tunnel goes down then so does the remote locations ability to print.  Is my thinking accurate? Is there a standard solution for a situation like this or is it normal to have a print server for each site? Thanks for you input

Comment: What OS is the print server?

Answer (score 0):

No, if there is only few people at the branch sites you could just map them directly to the printers.

you could have them go thru a print server at the main site, but the performance will really be affected by bandwidth and latency.  We do this for sites that only have a few local workstations/laptops and it works okay, most of those sites are T1 connections.

If your only going to have a domain controller at the main site, then loss of connectivity between the main site and branch site print servers would probably affect the local users ability to print anyways.  You do read only DCs with dns/wins/print services, but then you have to concern yourself with backup/recovery issues for the remote site servers.